# What would be idiomatic Corda "agreement" flow and state?

Tags: kotlin, corda

Given scenario that several >2 parties need to agree on some state before proceeding to "next stage" of whatever process is being implemented.

What would be current Corda (Corda 3.x) idiomatic approach for implemetnation, and how such state(s) would look like.

Some expected rules

1. More than 2 parties are invovled and each need to "agree" on the state to proceed on next stage
2. Agreement is "manual" so no code controls it, but party has to "press the button"
3. Press the button can be done only once per "document package" by any party, but the order can be arbitrary
4. If at least one party does "reject" button, the state exits.

How it can be simulated by flows and state transitions.

My initial idea would be to have linear state which besides classical "participants" contain similar list but with tracked "agreed" flag against each party. And corresponding initiator and acceptor flows and contract which tracks the rules, and whenever the list of participants has gathered all "agree" flags, then next stage of flow is triggered meaning - everybody agreed.

Can it be done more elegantly? Encumberances?

Answer (score 0):

You would define a state that tracks which parties have already agreed, out of the overall list of participants:

```
data class AgreementState(
        val partiesAgreed: List<Party>,
        override val participants: List<Party>,
        override val linearId: UniqueIdentifier) : LinearState
```

You would write a contract ensuring that for each transaction:

- The participants don't change
- Only one agreeing party is added
- The agreeing party is a participant
- The agreeing party is the required signer

  class AgreementContract : Contract {
      companion object {
          val ID = "com.template.AgreementState"
      }

  ```
  override fun verify(tx: LedgerTransaction) {
      val input = tx.inputsOfType<AgreementState>().single()
      val output = tx.outputsOfType<AgreementState>().single()
      val requiredSigner = tx.commands.single().signers.single()

      if (input.participants != output.participants) throw Exception()

      val changeInPartiesAgreed = (output.partiesAgreed - input.partiesAgreed)
      if (changeInPartiesAgreed.size != 1) throw Exception()

      val newPartyAgreeing = changeInPartiesAgreed.single()
      if (newPartyAgreeing !in output.participants) throw Exception()

      if (requiredSigner != newPartyAgreeing.owningKey) throw Exception()
  }

  class AddParty: CommandData
  ```

  }

And finally, we would write a flow that each party can invoke to signify its approval:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class AgreementFlow(val agreementState: StateAndRef<AgreementState>): FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    override fun call() {
        val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities[0]
        val inputState = agreementState.state.data
        val transactionBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary)
                .addInputState(agreementState)
                .addOutputState(inputState.copy(partiesAgreed = inputState.partiesAgreed + ourIdentity), AgreementContract.ID)
                .addCommand(AgreementContract.AddParty(), ourIdentity.owningKey)

        val stx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(transactionBuilder)
        subFlow(FinalityFlow(stx))
    }
}
```